# How to read DNS query log file

Tags: dns, logfile, logfile-analysis

I got a DNS internal query log file and I would like to do analysis on it, so onw record looks like this:

18-Jun-2017 04:00:10.139 client @XXXXXXXXXXXX ip-address#number (ip-address): view internal: query: ip-address IN AAAA + (ip-address in the format of ipv4)

I am really new to this so I tried to search on line but I couldn't find what does the "+" mean in the record, and as far as I understand, AAAA should represent the ipv6 ip format, why I got a following ipv4 address following it ?

Can some one explain it to me what does this record means or some links I could read myself ?

Many thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

You're right AAAA (or the quad record) is for IPV6 addresses. The IPV6 addressing scheme allows for trailing or leading zeros to be omitted, so an IPV4 address of `192.169.1.1` may be represented as `00:00:00:00:C0:A8:01:01` which without the leading zeros is `C0:A8:01:01` or `192.168.1.1` if your text editor converts Hex to Decimal.

Comment: Hi Arsh, so you are saying that actually the "IPv4 address" following the + sign is actually a formatted Ipv6 address ? and what does the "+" sign mean ? I couldn't find it anywhere online

Comment: Yes, the  address following the + is an IPV4 address that is formatted as as IPV6 address with leading zeros. I guess the reason that is happening is because the domain owner set an AAAA record which is actually an IPV4 address.

I don't have a solid answer for the + sign but I would guess it's just a formatting thing for the log file